# Why is a number having greater than 15 digits auto rounded in javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, rounding

I have a problem with javascript number. My problem is that I have a currency field in HTML and when I use javascript to calculate with another field; then if this input field has the number of digits > 15 then this is auto rounded.
You can try this in firebug. E.g:

```
(9999999999999999);
10000000000000000
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You have a ***currency*** field that you care is rounding past 9999999999999999??

I'm impressed right there :P

It's a limitation of having large floating point numbers.  There's no easy way to fix it short of getting a bigint javascript library, I'm sure there's a few out there.  But honestly, why do you care?

Comment: Javascript numbers aren't 32-bit.  They're IEEE-754 doubles, which take 64 bits: 1 sign, 11 exponent, 52 (explicit) mantissa.

Comment: @Ken, yes you're right, I'm tired.  It's a limitation of floating point numbers.  Better?  :)